# location.replace inconsistencies with url fragments

Tags: javascript

I recently noticed that `location.replace` doesn't actually reload the page when there there is an url fragment (`#`) in both the current url and the target url:

```
// Assume the current url is /#url-fragment
window.location.replace('/#my-new-url-fragment');
// Doesn't reload the page.
```

I am looking for a reliable, cross-browser way (supporting IE8) to replace the current url without adding to history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I could manage, but it isn't a very thorough answer. It is more of a trial-and-error then actually rationalizing behavior.

I built a table of all possible scenarios and then a script to check the outcomes. The logic that worked under all conditions was:

```
window.location.replace(url);

/* If the target url has a hash, and ignoring hashes the two urls match,
   then the location.replace() call above *did not reload the page*. Do so now. */

var urlWithoutHash = ...; // /test#hash -> /test
var currentUrlWithoutHash = ...;
if (url.indexOf('#') >= 0 && urlWithoutHash == currentUrlWithoutHash)
    window.location.reload();
```